# Old oscilloscope has its plastic screen slightly shifted, is it safe to use?

Tags: oscilloscope

I found an [HP 1220A oscilloscope](https://www.radiomuseum.org/r/hewlett_pa_zweikanaloszilloskop_1220.html) in a thrift store.

It's in pretty good shape, but I noticed its front green/blue plastic screen is a bit shifted to the right.

I can slide it back in place with my hand? I just want to make sure this isn't a safety issue. I assume all the plastic does is change the contrast as [explained here.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/334220)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be fine. The acual CRT is a sealed glass tube so you don't get exposed to any of the high-voltage stuff.

It would be worth taking the cover off and fixing it in place so the grid doesn't move about. It may also protect you if something did hit the tube and cause it to shatter.